# Deploying To Heroku Application Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, deployment, ruby-on-rails-4

I present to you the longest log you will ever see. I'm working my way through Hartl's tutorial and everything is fine until I try to push the app to heroku. I get the error "**Application Error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.
If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.**"

Not sure where I'm going wrong. I've been trying to figure this out for the better part of 3 hours. Any help is appreciated.

```
2013-12-08T10:22:44.588867+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2013-12-08T10:22:44.588867+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.0.1 application starting
 in production on http://0.0.0.0:46179
2013-12-08T10:22:44.588867+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more s
tartup options
2013-12-08T10:22:44.588867+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2013-12-08T10:22:44.588867+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2013-12-08T10:22:44.589578+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/
activemodel-4.0.1/lib/active_model/deprecated_mass_assignment_security.rb:14:in
`attr_accessible': `attr_accessible` is extracted out of Rails into a gem. Pleas
e use new recommended protection model for params(strong_parameters) or add `pro
tected_attributes` to your Gemfile to use old one. (RuntimeError)
```

---

Edit: This is what happens when I take out attr_accesible. I can get it on heroku now without it but I get these rspec errors. Any idea?

```
 ' c:\Sites\sample_app>bundle exec rspec spec/
including Capybara::DSL in the global scope is not recommended!
.F.............F......FF..FFF..

Failures:

  1) User pages signup with valid information should create a user
     Failure/Error: expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)

       count should have been changed by 1, but was changed by 0
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:46:in `block (4 levels) in <top (requi
red)>'

  2) User
     Failure/Error: it { should be_valid }
       expected #<User id: nil, name: nil, email: nil, created_at: nil, updated_
at: nil, password_digest: nil, password: nil> to be valid, but got errors: Passw
ord can't be blank, Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters), Name can't
be blank, Email can't be blank, Email is invalid, Password confirmation can't be
 blank
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) User when email address is already taken
     Failure/Error: user_with_same_email.email = @user.email.upcase
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `upcase' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:79:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  4) User when email format is valid should be valid
     Failure/Error: @user.should be_valid
       expected #<User id: nil, name: nil, email: "user@foo.COM", created_at: ni
l, updated_at: nil, password_digest: nil, password: nil> to be valid, but got er
rors: Password can't be blank, Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters),
Name can't be blank, Password confirmation can't be blank
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:71:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:69:in `each'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:69:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  5) User return value of authenticate method with valid password
     Failure/Error: it { should == found_user.authenticate(@user.password) }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `authenticate' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:43:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  6) User return value of authenticate method with invalid password
     Failure/Error: let(:user_for_invalid_password) { found_user.authenticate("i
nvalid") }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `authenticate' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:47:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:49:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  7) User return value of authenticate method with invalid password
     Failure/Error: let(:user_for_invalid_password) { found_user.authenticate("i
nvalid") }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `authenticate' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:47:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:50:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.37081 seconds
31 examples, 7 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:45 # User pages signup with valid infor
mation should create a user
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:19 # User
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:83 # User when email address is already taken
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:67 # User when email format is valid should be
valid
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:43 # User return value of authenticate method w
ith valid password
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:49 # User return value of authenticate method w
ith invalid password
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:50 # User return value of authenticate method w
ith invalid password'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in you trace errors

```
`attr_accessible` is extracted out of Rails into a gem. Please
 use new recommended protection model for params(strong_parameters) 
 or add `protected_attributes` to your Gemfile to use old one.
```

dont use `attr_accessible` in Rails 4

Comment: Now, attr_accesible taken out lets me launch to heroku but now I get errors in my rspec tests.Check them out in my original post.

Comment: i dont see your `spec`

Comment: it is not relevant to your question

Comment: is not the way the stack

Comment: Should I make a whole new question then? I fix 1 thing but it breaks another.

Comment: if I answered your question and ask it to confirm the following in another thread